# Problems with the DNS Network part (or maybe virus/malware-related) on Android 6.0 Marshmallow (Alcatel Vendor)

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, connection-issues, malware, dns

I've been experiencing some strange problems maybe that be related with the DNS Network part in Android 6.0 Marshmallow, and could mention these two origins as the main likely sources of problems:

• Due to recent Network changes, as the adding of a new Router on the Network, the same that might have caused some conflicts recently;

• Maybe due or the low quality signal or an insatisfatory range on the space of my Home on my Wi-Fi Repeater, that insists in to fail sometimes recently, and also, maybe, needs to be resetted, for clean its cache, avoiding conflicts and mal-function.

I could mention that in Google Chrome for Android, is common to occur these two error codes below:

- "ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE";

. And this last error shown, after a power offing of Wi-Fi, and after yet of this action a Restart of the OS, for so then power on again the Wi-Fi, all DNS Network resolvings stayed going back to function correctly during a certain period of time:

- "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" .

*( according to this webpage, DNS related:

**<https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/557992-how-can-i-fix-err_name_not_resolved-my-sg4.html>** )

**Note:** Only Incognito Mode on Google Chrome works Ok for now. The YouTube, Mozilla Firefox and Google Play all them are currently refusing to work correctly on my initial tests.

**URL Address References:**

**<https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0sv0YttC20cU/?hl=en>**

Browsing on the Web on my Smartphone since yesterday is being problematic.

This page below, describes the main reasons for the DNS problems on Android 6.0 codenamed Marshmallow (or maybe serves to other versions too):

**<http://www.androidbeat.com/2015/12/how-to-fix-wi-fi-problems-android-6-0-marshmallow/>**

. Reading this Article above superficially initially, I could confirm that only a Restart resolved temporarily the problem (or an 'issue' how you may prefer to call it) for me at the moment, and I stayed knowing that only Incognito Mode is working correctly for now (using this Google Product Forums Reference):

**[Chrome keeps telling me that site can't be reached?](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0sv0YttC20cU/?hl=en)**

After, the same problems/issues back to occur again, as if nothing had been done in respect. Practically only Google, and some https Forum websites are loading and finishing its page loadings, these without any errors on the Google Chrome normal mode. My Android is configured with the DHCP Mode, so it's sounds like as strange that a conflict can still be there, if DHCP resolves the things automatically on the Network (as my understanding about these knowledges), without any intervention of the user. Doing on/off of my Wi-Fi on my Smartphone equiped with Android Marshmallow, normally would help on the DNS problem. I don't touched in any DNS parts since a long time ago, and I don't remember what I've did to fix DNS resolvings problems when it started to occur at that last time. The Advanced Configurations on Wi-Fi are hidden on my Android Smartphone (signal that these parts should not be altered, without any knowledge prior this -- I haven't altered anything there).

As all the solutions on this page below are esgoted:

**<http://www.androidbeat.com/2015/12/how-to-fix-wi-fi-problems-android-6-0-marshmallow/>**

seems like or this is a inconsistence on Network DNS part (that I'm not aware how to resolve and diagnose), or a recent bug introduced by Google on Android recently (again?), as described on the above provided url address. Drastic solutions, in addition to the procedures that I already performed as "clean cookies on the web browsers" or "restart the mobile device", procedures like "restore the device to the original factory settings" will be totally avoided here.

Any thoughts? Is there an App for Android that automatically finds and resolves DNS problems, or inconsistences on Android, available on Google Play Store? Don't knows about any logical solution, or trivial fix, because I'm a newbie when the subject is Network. And my Android is closed for alterations, so, despite as I'm experienced and familiar with Linux commands, I still can not properly use the Terminal Emulator on my Android from Alcatel, because many functions on the ROM from Alcatel Vendor are locked for access and alterations by the user, these customizations coming from the Manufacturer.

Please ask me for more information, if do you see this as necessary.

No more information I could provide here at the moment, except if asked by some of you here on this Forum.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526

Answer (score 1):

Try the new [Cloudflare app "1.1.1.1"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloudflare.onedotonedotonedotone)  It will give you privacy enhanced DNS which will circumvent your ISP.

I am not associated with the app or its vendor.

I recently learned that my mobile vendor provides my phone with its DNS results.  I had been under the impression that Google DNS servers were always used by Android.  Whether my mobile provider is providing DNS through proxy or DHCP, I don't know.  I don't care.  I don't want them seeing my requests.  The "1.1.1.1" app prevents it.  It would also provide you with highly reliable DNS independent of your mobile provider.

Answer (score 0):

**NEVERMIND** (for the moment). Maybe was the ISP that was having problems on the Network by some instability on the environment of the Internet Provider. Now the Internet access is correct. If the problems come back, I'll reopen this Topic. Never had seen this kind of problems happening before on my Mobile Internet Browsing experiences.